# What is the namespace for IMvcServiceLocator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

A number of articles reference `IMvcServiceLocator` for customizing service location in MVC3.

I'm assuming they were using the preview, but I've just upgraded to the RC, and the type can't be found.

Is this something that's changed with the RC, or am I missing a reference (I've downloaded various complete examples and they're broken too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it changed with the Beta: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html